# Starts with and full text search on same field in one query using RavenDB

Tags: c#, ravendb

I have an object with a string field stored in a RavenDB. For example:

```
public class SomeObject
{
    public string SomeText = "hello world";
}
```

I want to be able to check both of the following in the **same query**:

1. Checking if the entire string starts with a certain value. In this case:

   - "hell" would match
   - "hello" would match
   - "hello w" would match
   - "world" would **not** match
   - "world hello" would **not** match
2. Checking if the string contains certain terms. Assuming they are space separated, in this case:

   - "hell" would **not** match
   - "hello" would match
   - "hello w" would **not** match
   - "world" would match
   - "world hello" would match

What is a good way to setup the indexing (I assume?) to be able to do this in the same query?

Edit: Clarified that I want to be able to check both things in the same query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding two fields to an index, both based on `SomeText`.

One analyzed using the `StandardAnalyzer` and the other using the `LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer`.

This allowed me to do starts with searches using the field indexed by the `LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer`. Using the field indexed by the `StandardAnalyzer` would have generated a hit if **any** of the terms starts with whatever instead of the **entire string** starting with it.

Searching for terms can be done in parallel using the field indexed by the `StandardAnalyzer`.

I don't know if this is the best solution but it solved my problem.

Comment: Can you post the code for how you were able to get starts with to work?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [here](http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/2.5/Csharp/client-api/querying/static-indexes/searching). I guess you could do a combination of a `Where(n => n.StartsWith(...))` and `Search(...)` query.

Comment: I'm trying to understand this conceptually, please tell me if I'm wrong. If I, as per the link, create an index `documentStore.DatabaseCommands.PutIndex("SomeObjectsBySomeText", new IndexDefinition
{
 Map = "from someObject in docs.SomeObjects select new { someObject.SomeText }",
 Indexes = { { "SomeText", FieldIndexing.Analyzed } }
});` it will use the StandardAnalyzer (terms "hello" and "world") instead of the LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer (term "hello world"). If I then call `Where(o => o.SomeText.StartsWith("wor"))`, will it match or not? And why?